# how to display date in 2 tables then use where between date [MYSQL]

Tags: mysql, sql

this is my first time accessing stackoverflow, i have a problem in my query

**this query**

```
SELECT t1.DateA, t2.DateB
FROM tbl_date_a  t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT DateB
    FROM tbl_date_b  
    GROUP BY DateB
) t2
ON t1. DateA = t2.DateB
WHERE t1.DateA OR t2.DateB BETWEEN '2022-09-06' AND '2022-09-08'
GROUP BY t1.DateA
```

**this my query results**
[image results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/na3tA.png)

the problem is, when i add a data in tbl_date_b with DateB 2022-09-08, but it doesn't show up in results view, but if i add data in tbl_date_a with DateA 2022-09-08. then the data will appear. i know the problem is in left join because it is used in tbl_date_a.
. how to find a solution in this problem?

**the result expected is like this**
[image expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHVkE.png)

thank you very much for the help, I hope this problem is resolved quickly

**Solve Query By FrankSchmitt**

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post essential information as screenshots - it renders screen readers pretty useless.

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: How do I change all that, I'm so new here?

Comment: Change `WHERE t1.DateA BETWEEN '2022-09-06' AND '2022-09-08' OR t2.DateB BETWEEN '2022-09-06' AND '2022-09-08'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need a `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

*UPDATE* Since MySQL doesn't support this, you can emulate it by using two `LEFT JOIN`s and a `UNION`:

```
SELECT t1.DateA, t2.DateB
FROM tbl_date_a  t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT DateB
    FROM tbl_date_b  
    GROUP BY DateB
) t2
ON t1.DateA = t2.DateB
WHERE t1.DateA BETWEEN '2022-09-06' AND '2022-09-08'
GROUP BY t1.DateA

UNION 

SELECT t1.DateA, t2.DateB
FROM 
(
    SELECT DateB
    FROM tbl_date_b  
    GROUP BY DateB
) t2

LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_date_a  t1
ON t1.DateA = t2.DateB
WHERE t2.DateB BETWEEN '2022-09-06' AND '2022-09-08'
GROUP BY t2.DateB
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd56b0/1)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but full outer join gives an error message

Comment: @ErgestBasha yes i got that information, full outer join not support in mysql

Comment: @ErgestBasha Thanks for pointing this out (you should never assume that a RDBMS supports a given SQL feature without testing it first). I've rewritten it to use a workaround.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt thank you very much, this is very helpful, before i check, i have used left outer join, but there is problem in sum because i have extra value, but it works fine, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the result you want you have to use FULL OUTER JOIN, because T1 don't have the key 2022-09-08 to make a LEFT JOIN. and add a explicit condition to T1 inside WHERE.

And one good advice is to use parenthesis when working with "OR"

So your query shoud be like this:

```
SELECT t1.DateA, 
       t2.DateB
FROM tbl_date_a  t1
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT DateB
    FROM tbl_date_b  
    GROUP BY DateB
) t2
ON t1. DateA = t2.DateB
WHERE (t1.DateA BETWEEN '2022-09-06' AND '2022-09-08') OR (t2.DateB BETWEEN '2022-09-06' AND '2022-09-08')
GROUP BY t1.DateA
```